# Swift 2/3 String implement of rindexOf method

Tags: swift, string, indexing

I know there is an build in method to get the index of substring from the original string by using `rangeOfString`. But it is used to get the **first occurrence** of a given substring. However what I need to do is to get the **last occurrence** of the given substring.

This is something like the `rindex` in python language

So, my question is, How can I do that in Swift 2.x/3? A code snippet example is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Try the below, adding the optional options parameter and searching the string from the back instead.

```
let myString = "testingteststring"
let lastSubstringRange = myString.range(of: "test", options: String.CompareOptions.backwards)
```

'lastSubstringRange' will be the range of the last 'test' substring in 'myString'. 
For more info, try looking at Apple Developer: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1642786-range

Comment: Hope it helps, just ran into something similar a few days ago and didn't know about `String.CompareOptions.backwards`